# How to add tooltip error message to textbox that is bound to int property in WPF using MVVM Light

Tags: wpf, xaml, mvvm, mvvm-light

Let's say I have a simple WPF that has textbox that is bound in two ways to an integer property. This is XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <TextBox Text="{Binding Number, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"/>
</Grid>
```

MVVM model:

```
public class MyModelView : ViewModelBase
{
    public int Number
    {
        get
        {
            return _number;
        }
        set
        {
            _number = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged();
        }
    }
    private int _number;
}
```

Now if I put in `TextBox` something that is not integer, for example, `"ABC"`, the `TextBox` border becomes red, which signifies that `"ABC"` cannot be converted to `int`. 
What I want is to have a hover over message or a `ToolTip` on my `TextBox` with a custom error message, for example, `"ABC cannot be converted to integer, please put a valid integer number"`. I emphasize, the error message has to be custom, not a default one.
Can anyone provide some insight on how to achieve that?

Comment: I think [this is roughly what you're looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161523/wpf-validation-errors-setting-tooltip-with-error-message).

Comment: @EdPlunkett thanks, if I use `<TextBox Text="{Binding Number, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" 
                 ToolTip="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=(Validation.Errors)[0].ErrorContent}"/>` I manage to have a tooltip error message, but this one is a default one, I need to replace it with a custom string, any ideas?

Comment: Have you tried implementing `IDataErrorInfo` on the viewmodel, to provide an error message string?

Comment: @EdPlunkett I did and it didn't  work, I guess it doesn't work because `IDataErrorInfo` works on properties of `ViewModel` itself, but in this case property `Number` is not yet set because `Number` cannot be equal to `ABC`, so the error happens during conversion stage.

Comment: Oh right I wasn't thinking -- that's why you'd use ValidationRules instead: They do all their work in the view, so they can validate stuff like user typing letters in a numeric textbox.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF TextBox Validating results ToolTip](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2119494/wpf-textbox-validating-results-tooltip)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can anyone provide some insight on how to achieve that?

You could customize the error message using a `ValidationRule`:

```
public class StringToIntValidationRule : ValidationRule
{
    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, System.Globalization.CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        int i;
        if (int.TryParse(value.ToString(), out i))
            return new ValidationResult(true, null);

        return new ValidationResult(false, "Please enter a valid integer value.");
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<TextBox>
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="Number" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:StringToIntValidationRule ValidationStep="RawProposedValue"/>
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

Please refer to the following blog post for more information about this.

**Data validation in WPF:** https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/08/26/data-validation-in-wpf/